# GuzzleHttp resulted in 404 not found on a route that exists

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, guzzle, laravel-passport, laravel-5.7

I am sending request to `POST api.myserver.com/v1/oauth/token` to get a token with client_credentials as follows:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client; // A guzzle client
$response = $this->client->post('http://api.myserver.com/v1/oauth/token', [
  'form_params' => [
    'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
    'client_id' => 'MY_CLIENT_ID',
    'client_secret' => 'MY_CLIENT_SECRET',
    'scope' => ''
  ],
  'headers' => [
    'Accept' => 'application/json'
  ]
));
```

I am using [apiato](http://apiato.io/) framework so the default laravel passport token generating routes have been modified to something like `api.myserver.com/v1/oauth/token` and hence the path.

Now the code above is throwing a `404 not found exception` when I run it from the browser. It's working fine when I run it on [POSTman](https://www.getpostman.com/). And also it works fine when I run it in the test environment.

```
Client error: `POST http://api.myserver.com/v1/oauth/token` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" co (truncated...)
```

I tried changing the path to `http://myserver.com/oauth/token` with no luck. What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening to me specifically with the `client_credentials` grant_type. If I use `authorization_code` it works. Not sure why yet.

Answer (score -3):

Well, the reason you're getting 404 when you try to reach this endpoint using the browser is because it is a POST request. When you reach a URL via browser it is a GET request.

Comment: I am sending the POST request from a JavaScript client (axios)